# Is there a way in VBA to get the ListName parameter from a Sharepoint List when having as input only the URL?

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm constructing a tool in VBA that operates on Sharepoint data. I don't know how to approach lists though. I want to be able to use the list's url for the macro to download the list as table (just like in a web query .iqy).

I have found an earlier post about this but in objective-c:
[Sharepoint: GetList listName returning all list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17045012/sharepoint-getlist-listname-returning-all-list)

but I don't know how to do it in VBA. I was hoping this could be done without much markup language. Maybe sending a kind of query to sharepoint site and retrieving the parameter (with WinHttp.WinHttpRequest).
The funtion would utilize the below code. From the url I could extract the Server and ViewGUID but not the ListName unfortunately.

```
Sub ImportSharePointList()

    Dim objMyList As ListObject
    Dim objWksheet As Worksheet
    Dim strSPServer As String
    Const SERVER As String = "mysite:8003/sites/the-sharepoint-thing/"
    Const LISTNAME As String = "{D1F1C2ED-81BA-41CC-A698-XXXXXXXXXXXX}"
    Const VIEWNAME As String = "{27C9CA20-3293-4BD5-9271-XXXXXXXXXXXX}"

   ' The SharePoint server URL pointing to
   ' the SharePoint list to import into Excel.
    strSPServer = "http://" & SERVER & "/_vti_bin"
    ' Add a new worksheet to the active workbook.
    Set objWksheet = Worksheets.Add
    ' Add a list range to the newly created worksheet
    ' and populated it with the data from the SharePoint list.
    Set objMyList = objWksheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcExternal, _
        Array(strSPServer, LISTNAME, VIEWNAME), False, , Range("A1"))

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

What I was able to achieve is constructing an http query to the sharepoint API:

```
...
myUrl = [the address.aspx]

With theHttp
    .SetAutoLogonPolicy(AutoLogonPolicy_Always)
    .Open "GET", myUrl, False
    .Send
    resp = .ResponseText
End with
...
```

Then I just used Mid to take out the ListId.
The query retrieved all the data from the site(too much). Could somebody tell me howto retrieve only the ListId?